# google bigquery null column dropped in output when getting table content in CSV

Tags: google-bigquery

When getting table content in CSV, null columns get dropped in output.  Example:

curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" 
“https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJ_NAME/datasets/DATASET_NAME/tables/TESTNULL/data?alt=csv&startIndex=0&maxResults=10000”

the output is:

1,2,3

2,3,4

3,5

5

5,6

TESTNULL table contains 3 integer columns:

Row f1  f2  f3
1   1   2   3
2   2   3   4
3   3   null    5
4   null    null    5
5   5   6   null

The same query with alt=json works fine. Ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Just a question, maybe I'm dense... but how did you get the alt param for the request? I see it nowhere in the docs about the Rest API

Comment: I've never seen a rest api either.  if you google "bigquery get data in csv" or something similar, some posts will mention the alt=... parameter

Comment: my point is that the official BQ doc (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/list), there's nothing about that parameter, so I'm just trying to find something that explains the behavior

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the `alt=csv` output for table data list. The root cause has been identified and we are now tracking this issue in our internal bug tracker.

Thank you for the report!

Comment: Any ideas on when this will be fixed?  Some ppl in my organization is working with the BQ team and can file tickets.  Should they do so?  Thanks.